# Elegant and/or fast equivalents of Excel SUMXMY2 (sum of square of differences of corresponding array elements) in python

Tags: python, excel

Test Sample:

```
a = [0.1357678   0.27303184 -0.75600229]
b = [0.3813097  -0.72613616  0.18361217]
```

I would like to implement `SUMXMY2(a, b)` in Python without for loops

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Squared difference is given by:

```
c = ((a - b) ** 2)
```

The sum is then simply given by

```
c = c.sum()
```

if a and b are lists you can convert them to pandas series first:

```
a = pd.Series(a)
```

or to numpy array as:

```
a = np.asarray(a)
```

Comment: Only if a and b are numpy arrays. This doesn't work if they're lists.

Comment: @DavidBuck True, but you can convert your lists to numpy arrays or pandas seriesto achieve the desired results. I don't see a way of doing it for lists

Comment: with this I get a "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" error? a and b are arrays I'd like to do the SSD operation on the arrays at once without a for loop

Comment: @Quesop first convert a and b to a pandas Series or a numpy array, then use this solution. This way you don't need a for loop

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `-` is not a valid operator for lists, so I would use a list comprehension. It does technically use a for loop, however I'd call it "elegant enough".

```
c = [(b[i] - a[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(b))]
result = sum(c)
```

To make it more compact but less readable:

```
c = sum([(b[i] - a[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(b))])
```

If you're dealing with lists of different lengths, use this:

```
c = [(b[i] - a[i]) ** 2 for i in range(min(len(b), len(a)))]
result = sum(c)
```